# Bard-API Installation in R

Tags: package

How to install bard-api in r?

I have used "devtools::install_github("dsdanielpark/bard-api")" and getting the following error -
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
HTTP error 404.
Not Found

Did you spell the repo owner (`dsdanielpark`) and repo name (`bard-api`) correctly?

- If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo."